# Scraping a website with beautiful soup. But it cant scrape each <li> tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a complete beginner and I'm running into some issues in web scraping I'm able to scrape the picture, title, and price. And was successful at grabbing the index at `[0]` However, whenever I try to run a loop or hardcode the index at a higher value than 0 it states that it's out of range. And it won't scrape any of the other `<li>` tags. Is there any other way to go about this problem? Also, I incorporated selenium in order to load the entire page. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://ca.octobersveryown.com/collections/all")

scrolls = 22
while True:
    scrolls -= 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if scrolls < 0:
        break

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

bodies = (soup.find(id='content'))

clothing = bodies.find_all('ul', class_='grid--full product-grid-items')

for span_tag in soup.findAll(class_='visually-hidden'):
    span_tag.replace_with('')

print(clothing[0].find('img')['src'])
print(clothing[0].find(class_='product-title').get_text())
print(clothing[0].find(class_='grid-price-money').get_text())

time.sleep(8)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: clothing.find_all("li") Should give you all the li tags. Than loop and print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only `BeautifulSoup` without selenium, you can simulate Ajax requests the page is making. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://uk.octobersveryown.com/collections/all?page={page}&view=pagination-ajax'

page = 1
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser' )

    li = soup.find_all('li', recursive=False)
    if not li:
        break

    for l in li:
        print(l.select_one('p a').get_text(strip=True))
        print('https:' + l.img['src'])
        print(l.select_one('.grid-price').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
        print('-' * 80)

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
LIGHTWEIGHT RAIN SHELL
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1605/0171/products/lightweight-rain-shell-dark-red-1_large.jpg?v=1598583974
£178.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIGHTWEIGHT RAIN SHELL
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1605/0171/products/lightweight-rain-shell-black-1_large.jpg?v=1598583976
£178.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALL COUNTRY HOODIE
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1605/0171/products/all-country-hoodie-white-1_large.jpg?v=1598583978
£148.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT (To save as CSV):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://uk.octobersveryown.com/collections/all?page={page}&view=pagination-ajax'

page = 1
all_data = []
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url.format(page=page)).content, 'html.parser' )

    li = soup.find_all('li', recursive=False)
    if not li:
        break

    for l in li:
        d = {'name': l.select_one('p a').get_text(strip=True),
             'link': 'https:' + l.img['src'],
             'price': l.select_one('.grid-price').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')}
        all_data.append(d)
        print(d)
        print('-' * 80)

    page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                  name  ...            price
0               LIGHTWEIGHT RAIN SHELL  ...          £178.00
1               LIGHTWEIGHT RAIN SHELL  ...          £178.00
2                   ALL COUNTRY HOODIE  ...          £148.00
3                   ALL COUNTRY HOODIE  ...          £148.00
4                   ALL COUNTRY HOODIE  ...          £148.00
..                                 ...  ...              ...
271  OVO ESSENTIALS LONGSLEEVE T-SHIRT  ...           £58.00
272                OVO ESSENTIALS POLO  ...           £68.00
273             OVO ESSENTIALS T-SHIRT  ...           £48.00
274                 OVO ESSENTIALS CAP  ...           £38.00
275           POM POM COTTON TWILL CAP  ...  £32.00 SOLD OUT

[276 rows x 3 columns]
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much!! I've been sitting here stuck trying to figure out a better solution, rather than the blob I had.

Comment: However, if I wanted to put this data into a csv how would one go about doing that? as each thing is a print statement and not a variable.

Comment: ohh I see how you did it, thanks so much for helping out a newbie!!